# IE 7 offset increasing as child increases

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have very weird bug in my application. Where i show a list of questions one by one. When the page is opened in IE 7 the questions having an offset increasing as question increases.
[image]

I can't find the issue. I have tried a lot of css changes. but none of them worked out!
Please help me.

css code for each question div

```
.questions > .question {
display:block;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 40px;
position: relative;
clear: both;
margin: 0 0 1px 0;
left: 0px;
_left: 0px;
/*  border-left: 5px solid white; */
}
```

Comment: @adaam Its not right margin, it's margin bottom!

Comment: Yes forgive me read the shorthand wrong! Btw what is `_left` :S ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `HTML`, it looks like a tag is not being closed correctly.

Most modern browsers will correct this as they render the page, but IE7 can be pretty picky.

Additionally, make sure your page is in standards mode (by setting a valid `DTD`), or IE7 will not recognise that `>` direct child selector.

Answer (score 0):

All .question classes are within .questions div. right?

What about try this one? without `.questions >`

```
.question {
    display:block;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    left: 0px;
    _left: 0px;
   /*  border-left: 5px solid white; */
}
```